# Direct mapped cache, hit or miss?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I have a problem with exercise:

Cache DM. Cache size - 64kB, single line size - 64B. After turn on, procesor has read adresses:

- 0x00000
- 0x0003C
- 0x0013C
- 0xF0038
- 0x00015
- 0x00130

I have to say, when will be miss, and when will be hit. I have found a few examples of similar exercises to this, but I do not know what to do with adresses in hexdecimal. I know that: `Cache address = Memory Address **mod** Cache Size`, but I have no idea how can I solve this exercise.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer such questions is to find the `tag`, `index` and the `offset` bits of the given cache design. Then map the address access patterns into the corresponding tag, index to obtain the hit/miss information.

As an example consider access to address `0xF0038`:

```
Cache Size  = 64kB
Line Size   = 64B
Offset bits = log2(64) = 6
Index bits  = log2(6kB/64B) = 10
Considering 20-bit address line
Tag bits    = 20 - 10 - 6 = 4
Address accessed  - 0xF0038
Converting into bits - 
1111_0000_0000_0011_1000
Tag - 1111
Index - 0000_0000_00
Offset - 11_1000
```

Now, you know that the access is to index `0x0` with tag as `0xF`. Depending the earlier accesses it would be a miss or a hit. Similarly, you can do it for all the other addresses.